# Adaptive_width property of MDLabel is not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am making an app using **kivy & kivymd** and in one part of it, I would like the labels to take as much space as the actual text.

This seems pretty straightforward with kivy itself but for some reason, nothing works with the `MDLabel` class. I tried setting the `adaptive_width` property to `True` and I also tried to directly set the `width` to the `texture_size[0]` property but none of them worked (and yes I installed kivymd directly from github).

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
BoxLayout:
    MDLabel:
        text: "Supposedly adaptive width (KivyMD)"
        font_size: "21sp"
        halign: "center"
        adaptive_width: True
        # I also tried directly setting the width to the texture_size but the results were worse
        # size_hint_x: None
        # width: self.texture_size[0]
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .8, .1, .2, .5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    Widget:
    MDSeparator:
        orientation: "vertical"
    Widget:
    Label:
        text: "Actual adaptive width (Standard Kivy)"
        font_size: "21sp"
        color: 0, 0, 0, 1
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.texture_size[0]
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, .6, .2, .5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Here is my results:
[image: my results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe that `MDLabel` supports the `adaptive_width` property. In using the `width: self.texture_size[0]`, it seems that you must also add the `text_size: None, None` to the `MDLabel`, and it seems that its location in the `kv` is important. Here is a version of part of your `kv` that seems to work:

```
BoxLayout:
    MDLabel:
        text: "Supposedly adaptive width (KivyMD)"
        font_size: "21sp"
        halign: "center"
        # adaptive_width: True
        # I also tried directly setting the width to the texture_size but the results were worse
        size_hint_x: None
        width: self.texture_size[0]
        text_size: None, None  # added, and must be in this location
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: .8, .1, .2, .5
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, however, if you apply this (`on_parent: print([item for item in dir(self) if 'adaptive_' in item])`) to any `MDLabel` instance, you will see that there adaptive width id among them but for some reason it is not working.